# How to effeciently print names in database sorting according to a coloumn in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

More precisely . I have a table say 'data' , which has many coloumns out which 2 are : 'Name' & 'Score' being Text and Integer type respectively. Now without editing the actual table itself , i just need to print all the Names in decreasing order of Scores . I guess O(N^2) should work too as there are hardly 1000 entries . I am using php/mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

```
 SELECT name, score FROM data ORDER BY score DESC
```

PHP (mysqli). Assuming $db is your database connection:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name, score FROM data ORDER BY score DESC");
$stmt->execute;
$result = $stmt->get_result;
$stmt->close();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  echo $row['name'];
  echo ": ";
  echo $row ['score'];
  echo "</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but as far as i understand you just need the right MySQL query?

`SELECT name, score FROM data ORDER BY score DESC`

This would select all the names and their respective scores in descending order.

Then you just need to loop through it in a php file, printing them out on the page in whatever style suits you.

I hope it helps.

Cheers.